# How windows(7) gets executable location (from task manager)?

Tags: windows, cmd, virtualbox, batch-processing, wmic

I have a Portable VirtualBox set up on one of my hard drives ([Portable Virtual Box](http://www.vbox.me/)). And I have another VirtualBox installed in my system (this one is NOT portable, but classic installation in C:\Program Files)

I'm trying to use a BATCH Script to retrieve the location of the running VirtualBox:

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

ECHO Please make sure you have VirtualBox running, so the script
ECHO will be able to detect VirtualBox.exe process running

rem because of a bug in wmic, I have to get the Input Locale first.
rem I could have had it hardcoded, but I think this is better (more flexible)
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:,;" %%s in ('systeminfo ^| find /i "Input Locale:"') DO (
SET locale=%%~ns
set locale=!locale: =!
)

rem this is the actual search for the executable location
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I IN ('wmic process where "name='virtualbox.exe'" get ExecutablePath^,Handle /Format:"%WINDIR%/System32/wbem/!locale!/csv" ^| FIND /i "virtualbox.exe"') DO SET "exepath=%%~I"
ECHO Detected Path: !exepath!

endlocal
```

But I always get

> "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe".

I tried from Task Manager (right click > Open File Location) and it happens the same, no matter which of the VirtualBox instances is running.
Uninstalling the version in my "C:\Program Files" enabled proper detection of the portable one.

Is it any way (using BATCH) to correctly detect running process executable location (VirtualBox.exe, in my case), when the situation is similar with the one described above (running a portable version of an already installed program)?

Comment: The image path is read directly from the process environment block parameters. If the PEB says the executable is "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe", then that's what it is. It could be that the portable version somehow ends up using the registered version of virtualbox.exe instead of the portable version.

Comment: From a quick read of http://www.vbox.me/ even the portable version needs to install various drivers (temporarily). The portable version's drivers would propably conflict with the ones of the installed regular version, so it would be only logical for the portable version to launch the already installed version.

Comment: Don't forget about `get CommandLine` too just in case but easy enough to test and try just in case. Another quick thought but play with "`WHERE virtualbox.exe`" from elevated command prompt and see if you can get an expected result with it someway from batch if the WMIC isn't bringing back to the correct path value of the portable version... [`WHERE`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

Comment: @eryksun problem is that each of them load different virtual machines, so It's very confusing for me at this time.
Another puzzling thing is that if I start one VirtualBox, then I attempt to start the other one, it will actually start another instance of the already running one.

Plus, as I said, when starting only one of them, it loads the correct virtual machines (that were configured in the respective instance of VirtualBox).

Comment: Is there more than one (1) virtualbox.exe process running? The code would simply take the last one it saw in the loop.